# Column ordering in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8bxYr/215/

I want to order my divs in **mobile screen** and i'm using Bootstrap 3 .

recently i've read this Article: [Scotch](https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap) but i can't handle this

**Html :**

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
            should be below
        </div>
         <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             should be above in mobile screen
        </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Any advice ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll place the div you want to end up below in the second column, not the first. You also don't need all those col-*-* (col-xs-* won't stack on an xs viewport also)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well well-lg clearfix">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
        <div class="alert alert-info">should be above in mobile screen</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">should be below</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```